# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./dist/qs.js

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, browser-history, react-router

I use webpack and [history](https://github.com/rackt/history) (1.13.0) library for `react-router` as a npm dependency. When I build project I get error:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./dist/qs.js in /Users/and/p/node_modules/history/node_modules/qs
```

In [package.json](https://github.com/hapijs/qs/blob/master/package.json) of qs project is main file `lib/index.js`, but in [bower.json](https://github.com/hapijs/qs/blob/master/bower.json) `dist/qs.js`.

In `.../history/node_modules/qs` I don't have any [dist folder](https://github.com/hapijs/qs/tree/master/dist).

I am not sure if this is an issue, but now I can't use history module without manually changing main file path of **bower.json** of qs project.

Comment: Hm it works fine for me using webpack + same history version and react-router v1 :/

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when using the bower-webpack-plugin with react-router.

The only way I could resolve it was by manually changing the bower.json main entry to lib/index.js in the qs module in history dependency.